# Dynamically add ng-click in AngularJS when image was loaded

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to dynamically add `ng-click` to an element when an image source has been loaded. I'm doing this right now like this:

```
$scope.compile = function(element) {
  var el = angular.element(element);
  $scope = el.scope();
  $injector = el.injector();
  $injector.invoke(function($compile) {
    $compile(el)($scope)
  })
};

$scope.showImagePreview = function(url) {

  fabric.util.loadImage(url, function(image) {

    if (image) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {

        var myEl = angular.element(image);
        myEl.attr('ng-click', 'openImage()');
        $scope.compile(myEl);

        $('.img-preview').append(myEl);
        $scope.canOpenImage = true;
      });
    }
  });
};
```

But I keep getting an error - can not call invoke of undefined. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well m8, you did not provided your hole code so I can't give you a full qualified answer to this. IMO you should keep it simple. You don't need `fabric.js`, `$compile`, `$scope.$apply`, `$injector` or `angular.element()` to create such simple handling. You could easily do it with native JavaScript and the power of AngularJS. In that way take a look at this simple approach.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <a ng-click="openImage()">
     <img ng-src="{{src}}" ng-click="" loaded-state="imageLoaded" imageonload />
   </a>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.src = 'https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150';
    $scope.imageLoaded = false;
    $scope.openImage = function () {
      if ($scope.imageLoaded) {
        //function allowed to execute when image was loaded
        console.log($scope.imageLoaded);
      }
    }
});

myApp.directive('imageonload', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          loadedState: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {
               scope.loadedState = true;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

#### >> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/994Lc7zp/)

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation!